# Angularjs directive and now onclick is slow

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, angularjs-directive

I recently re-factored a bit of html into a directive.  The original HTML had an ng-click attribute that called a function in the control and cleared out a data field.  Its fast.  But when I re-factored it into a directive, there is a lag between the button press and the clearing of the field.

```
.directive('evFilterbox', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
        return {
            restrict: "EA",
            template: function (el, at) {
                return "<div class=\"filterbox\">"
                        + "<div class=\"input-group\">"
                        + "<input id=\"input-"+ at.id +"\" class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\""
                        + " tooltip=\"{{tt." + at.id + "}}\""
                        + " placeholder=\"{{pp." + at.id + "}}\""
                        + " ng-model=\"data." + at.id + "\">"
                        + "<span id=\"span-"+at.id +"\" class=\"input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-remove\"></span>"
                        + "</div></div>";
            },
            replace: true,
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                $('#span-' + attrs.id).bind('click', function() {
                    scope.data[attrs.id] = '';
                });
            }
        };
    }])
```

Any comments on improving this directive are welcome.

Comment: I think you need to apply the scope **inside** of the event handler: `scope.$apply(function () { scope.data[attrs.id] = ''; });`. The handler is outside the context of Angular's digest cycle, so you need to force the UI to update

Comment: chaching!   That was it, thanks

Comment: Seriously tho, ditch jQuery. document.getElementById, querySelector, and addEventListener. Money.

Comment: @ZackArgyle Other than `document.getElementById`, jQuery provides cross-browser consistency (that `querySelector` and `addEventListener` **especially** don't have), so no, don't ditch jQuery. At the same time, Angular provides an internal selection system, `angular.element`, that uses a light version of jQuery, or jQuery itself if it's included on the page. Other than listing things that jQuery effectively fixes support for, you should provide a real reason why to "ditch jQuery"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `link` function to this:

```
function (scope, element, attrs) {
    $('#span-' + attrs.id).bind('click', function() {
        scope.$apply(function () {
            scope.data[attrs.id] = '';
        });
    });
}
```

This will make the `$digest` loop run.

Answer (score 0):

The lag is due to using jQuery (not that jQuery is slow).

Making a DOM change with jQuery does not start a `$digest` cycle. It is not until something else in your angular app starts a `$digest` that your view will be updated.

I recommend you either use `ng-click` in your template, or add `scope.$apply`:

```
$('#span-' + attrs.id).bind('click', function() {
  scope.$apply(function() { // Starts a $digest.
    scope.data[attrs.id] = '';
  });
});
```